# What is the result of (λx.λy.x + ( λx.x+1) (x+y)) ( λz.z-4 5) 10?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Could you explain what should I do about

> λx.λy.x

part?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the numbers encoded in the standard way in $\lambda$-calculus ? If yes, $\lambda x.\lambda y.x$ is $0$.

Comment: also it seems that you got your parenthesis wrong, since y appears later, it is probably in the scope of the first $\lambda y$.

Comment: I'm guessing the plus binds tighter, so $\lambda x.\lambda y.x$ is not an individual part.

Comment: @dkuper paranthesis should be true.

Comment: if the parenthesis are true, then you have a $y$ floating in your formula, so it does not evaluate to a number. Or as @Samuel says, the + binds tighter, but it is not not standard so parenthesis should be put to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: and the least we can say is that the status of $(\lambda z.z-4~5)$ is ambiguous, parenthesis should put here to clarify the order of operations. Is it 45 or 4 apply to 5, or (z-4) applied to 5 ?, or $(\lambda z.(z-4))$ applied to $5$ ?

Comment: @dkuper there is a space between 4 and 5.

Comment: The only way to get a number in the end is the parenthesis I put in the answer. otherwise your $z$ is left hanging. It corresponds in your expression to "-" having priority over ".", having itself priority over application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are pretty bad, here is my guess on what the expression should be in order to evaluate to a number in the end:

$(\lambda x.\lambda y.(x + ( \lambda x.x+1) (x+y)))~( (\lambda z.(z-4))~5)~10$

Then you just have to reduce everything.
Here is a step-by-step reduction:

$$\begin{array}{l}
(\lambda x.\lambda y.(x + ( \lambda x.x+1) (x+y)))~( (\lambda z.(z-4))~5)~10\\
\to (\lambda x.\lambda y.(x + (x+y+1)))~(5-4)~10\\
\to (\lambda x.\lambda y.(2x+y+1))~1~10\\
\to (\lambda y.(2*1+y+1))~10\\
\to (2*1+10+1)\\
\to 13
\end{array}$$

Comment: I followed these steps : 
 (λx.λy.(x+(λx.x+1)(x+y))) ((λz.(z−4)) 5) 10
= (λx.λy.(x+(λx.x+1)(x+y))) 1 10
=(λx.λy.(13)) = 13
is that true?

Comment: the $13$ is good, but the intermediate steps are weird. In particular the last one is not correct. I put the correct steps in the answer.